# Generalizing ROW() and SUM() - excel

Tags: excel, sum, row

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
=SUM(A(ROW()):E(ROW()))
```

so this formula would take a sum of all the elements from column A to E in the current row.
Is this possible or should I take some other approach?

I have a lot of data that depends on the sum in this way and I don't want to waste time by typing for each row some other number so I'm trying to figure out how to GENERALIZE the formula.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Do you know how the `fill` function work in excel? You write the formula for one row, and click-drag the little black square (in the lower right corner of the selected cell) down. The row number should update automatically to match the row in which the formula is.

Comment: Yes, I've already used it just a few moments ago, but it's still far easier to just generalize a formula and copy-paste it into a cell. Thx for suggestion tho...

Comment: You can use `autosum` (that's a button in the home menu and not an actual formula) to generate the formula for you, and just click-drag or double-click the little black square. Copy/pasting works as well, as you have noted.

Comment: Yep I just noticed. I'm currently playing with Excel so I'm figuring stuff on the go. Btw, I'm still curious if there is something like the formula posted in the question... Would be really handy if there was such way to generalize the formula. I'm mostly using my keyboard (hate to use mouse - slow and unproductive). Besides I got more formulas that depend on a similar way. Example: I need to calculate the grade for a student depending on the sum of all the points on a test. I know how to write it but I would like to be able to generalize it. Thx again for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I get what you're looking for exactly, you could maybe use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:E,ROW(),1):INDEX(A:E,ROW(),5))
```

You could also use the shortcut for autosum: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: Personally I'd always go with `=SUM(A2:E2)` for row 2 copied down - this version, though, will also do the same as Jerry's suggestion `=SUM(INDEX(A:E,ROW(),0))`